# How to calculate $P(X<x | Y= \pm y)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose that $X, Y$  are gaussian random variables with mean $\mu_x, \mu_y$ respectively, the same variance $\sigma^2$ and the covariance $cov(X,Y)= \rho \sigma^2$. It is easy to calculate $P(X<x | Y= y)$. We can just calculate the corresponding conditional density $f(x|y)$ first, and integrate it over the desired domain. But How do we calculate $P(X<x | Y= \pm y)$ given two possible values on the condition?

Comment: Are you looking for $\mathsf{P}(X<x\mid |Y|=y)$?

Comment: The probability of $|Y|$ taking the single value $y$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
$$P(X<x\mid Y=\pm y)=\frac{P(X<x\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)+P(X<x\mid Y=-y)f_Y(-y)}{f_Y(y)+f_Y(-y)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do we have the sum of two densities on the denominator and multiples of density and probability? Sorry for the novice question.

Comment: The denominator is $P(Y=\pm y)$ and the numerator is $P(X \lt x, Y=y)+P(X \lt x, Y = -y)$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674527/61578